# Tumblr API v2 CodeIgniter cannot make GET authenticated request

Tags: php, codeigniter, tumblr

I'm trying to use some GET Tumblr endpoint using this Tumblr CodeIgniter wrapper https://github.com/theprestig3/CI-Tumblr-APIv2-Library, my problem is that I want to authenticate via OAuth the GET request (to avoid hammering the limits). For now I want to search posts that have certain tag, if I specify the api key, the request is successful no matter if the token is valid or not (so I'm guessing is not authorising the request properly with the OAuth). In POST methods, like for example "liking a post", there's no problem.

**Update**: I successfully did an authenticated request but with no parameters (/user/info endpoint). So I'm guessing the problem should reside in the parameters part

The code looks like this:

Controller:

```
$settings = array(
                'access_token' => $token,
                'access_token_secret' => $secret 
            );

            $tumblr = new Tumblr($settings);

            $result = $tumblr->tagged($tag, null, $limit);
```

Modified tagged method in library:

```
function tagged($tag, $limit, $before = NULL)
    {
        if(isset($this->access_token) && isset($this->access_token_secret)){
            $urlParams;
            if(!isset($before)){
                $urlParams = '?tag='.$tag.'&limit='.$limit.'&filter=text';
                // $urlParams = '?tag='.$tag.'&limit='.$limit.'&filter=text'.'&api_key='.$this->tumblr_consumer_key;
            }else{
                $urlParams = '?tag='.$tag.'&limit='.$limit.'&filter=text'.'&before='.$before;
                // $urlParams = '?tag='.$tag.'&limit='.$limit.'&filter=text'.'&before='.$before.'&api_key='.$this->tumblr_consumer_key;
            }
            return $this->connection->get($this->host .'tagged' . $urlParams);
        }
        else{
            return json_decode($this->http($this->host . 'tagged/', '_GET', array('api_key' => $this->tumblr_consumer_key, 'tag' => $tag, 'before' => $before, 'limit' => $limit, 'filter' => 'text' )));
        }
    }
```

[Original Tumblr Library is here.](https://github.com/theprestig3/CI-Tumblr-APIv2-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/Tumblr.php)

Comment: please post only code that allows to help you, check this page http://sscce.org/

Comment: I trimmed the code a little

Comment: @CharlesB you shouldn't have deleted the piece of code I wrote because that was a modification in the library to make that request the authenticated way